# Understanding the behavior of my mistake

Tags: led, transistors, circuit-analysis

Few days ago, I receive the PCB I ordered, solder all the chip, and upload the program in the microcontroler. Unfortunately, I made a very huge mistake in my design. For some reason, I invert the diode sense in a RGB diode :

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fc9wRU.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

I know there is no way to fix that mistake so I have to do the entier schematic, board and PCB again.

By inverting every diode sense, none of them works... But one, the one in the middle remains on regardless of the input.

[image]

I double check every parts on the board, check resistor value, possible short circuit and I found nothing. I wonder if it's another design mistake or if it's an effect from the previous error.

Here is the schematic for one RGB LED, the part in the box is repeated for each color:

Note that the LED orientation is as on the board. (upside down)

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f5I6N7.png)</sup>

"PWM" and "Segment selection" signals come from a microcontroler. Whatever the logic level of these two signals, the LED remains on.

I'm running out of idea right know. I'd like to know where does problem come from before I restart the design. (So what I can avoid the same mistake if there is one)

Let me know if you want more information (resistor value, transistor gain, part number...)

Comment: 2 brief comments: (a) that unexpected light looks green, not white. If so, then that difference (i.e. no red or blue) may be helpful when diagnosing the problem i.e. ask yourself why that LED is treated differently. (b) If I had that PCB in front of me, I would be using a multimeter or 'scope to probe the PCB, including comparing voltages between lit and unlit LEDs, and find where the driving voltage (for the lit LED) is coming from, and where *that* is coming from, step-by-step. When you find out *what* is happening, then you can start to answer your question about *why* it is happening.

Comment: If the LED is rotated by 90° you might get that fault but zooming in on the photo it seems to be correctly mounted. Hmmm.

Comment: (1) Claim that each RGB has the same circuit. (2) Claim that RGB is really common anode, rather than common cathode as design required. (3) Fact that center RGB LED is on (one or more of them), when powered (no discussion about if software is running, though.) (4) Fact that it's impossible for any of them to be on, unless positive rail is available to anode. From this, I'd assume you have somehow managed to short the anode side (bottom) to +5 V. (How else is (+) getting to the anode?) But if so, then there is indeed a path to ground through two resistors. I'd be looking at the collector of Q1.

Comment: @SamGibson There is a bit of red as well, can not be seen in the picture. I have no 'scope but using a multimeter, I seen 1.7V on Q1 base when "Segment selection" is low...

Comment: @jonk I'm still looking for short circuit with my multimeter but I can't find any so far. Even if it's not working at the moment, was the design good (if the led were in the good orientation)?

Comment: @Transistor What if it's rotated 180°? I think that'd light one of the three colours if voltage is applied...

Comment: I think @jonk is on the right track.  5 volts reverse voltage is right at the edge of what these diodes can handle, so I'm betting that you have blown the other two shorted.  When you turn off Q1, the one remaining diode sees power back through R3 and R4.

Comment: @JohnBirckhead So I blown Q1 when I soldered it? In that case, why is the green LED brighter than the other one?

Comment: Did you turn you meter on to AC mode? Comes in handy now and again...

Comment: @M.Ferru Your eyes are far more sensitive to green. Given similar currents (and I don't have any information on that) and similar conversion efficiencies to light, you'd see green more easily. Why haven't you measured the voltage at the collector of your Q1 device? Just measure it. That will tell you something.

Comment: Providing the voltage at each of the 4 pins would help alot, plus the voltage across each 'R3' of the PWM driver

Comment: I think the diodes might be shorted.  Current path through Q2, R3, shorted Diode, then forward through the working diode.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with "... none of them (should) work...".  The fact that the middle LED works, shows that you have an additional problem with the PCB.  To verify this, modify one PCB to isolate the LEDs. Do this by cutting the common connection away from the plane and the other pins.  Use "external" wires to reconnect the common connection and the other pins correctly (in other words, reverse the connections).  While doing this, you might "stumble" into why the middle LED is not working as expected.  If not, continue the diagnosis until you fix it, then you can redo the PCB, knowing it will work as expected.